# How to perform Pose estimation for 3D object rendering in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I am developing a simple AR application which renders a 3D image on top of camera view. I could successfully implement that in Windows 7.I used OpenCv's native POSE estimation functions which internally uses POSIT algorithm, so as to give Translation, Rotation matrix, which could be applied on the the 3D modal.

I want to implement the same functionality in an Android application. The problem I am facing is, one of the arguments to the POSE estimation function is the Camera intrinsic and distortion parameters. Which i am not able to find out.
I tried studying various AR platforms - AandAR, ARToolKit etc. But after reverse engineering their Sources, i could get to any conclusion about usage of these in POSE estimation.

Please suggest me an appropriate method for POSE estimation (if it involves camera distortion parameters, then how would i determine it) and hence 3D object rendering over camera view in an Android application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org) is a great library, which gives you the methods to perform camera calibration, if you want to figure out what the intrinsic parameters of your camera are, see [Camera calibration documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html). Many of those functionalities are also implemented in the [Android OpenCV library](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

Finally you can also use the internal sensors Android ships with to obtain [Gravity, Linear Acceleration and Orientation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html). See this inspiring [talk by David Sachs on how to use Sensor Fusion on Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k).

Answer (score 0):

I was successfully able to perform Camera Calibration for the mobile device. I clicked chessboard snaps using the mobile camera, from various angles,and then used them in C++ Camera calibration code.

Then using these intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters, I was trying to make the POSE estimation module.

1. I parsed the XML files and build the matrices.
2. Then using this OpenCv tutorial - [OpenCv POSIT](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Posit) .I was able to perform POSE estimation.

However, I am yet to check its credibility over an actual program. But theoretically its achievable and code doesn't give any build or compilation error.